# Trigger.io Native modules and external libraries

Tags: trigger.io

I have developped a Native Module for `Trigger.io` that embeded an external `JAR` library.

Everything works well when I use the `ForgeInspector` android application. Everything work as expected.
However, things get bad when I upload the module on `trigger.io` platform for use in an application.

As soon as I call my native module methods, it triggers a `JAVA` error saying that the class embeded in the external library can not be found.

I have decompiled my generated application that calls my new module, and I can't find the library that was in the module I uploaded.

When I decompile the `ForgeInspector APK`, I can find this external library.

My conclusion is that there is something that doesn't work in `trigger.io` system, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you try copying your external `JAR` library to the `module/android/libs` folder in your `module` folder? See [using external libraries](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/external_libraries.html)

Comment: Yes. I have included the external in module/android/libs, but the generated apk using this module don't contain this jar file (so javascript calls don't work of course).